# How to let content editors use pre-defined block-like content?

Tags: 8, blocks, paragraphs

In wordpress (gutenberg), content editors can choose some kind of pre-defined blocks to their content. If I have content editors, that can create new nodes, I want them to be able to add such blocks into their content, but in a more drupal like way.

Let's say, the editor wants to create an article and wants to add a quote, a picture with a description or a Video with a description. I would assume, that I could create custom block types for these, to have the required fields and to create a design for these blocks.

But:

- The editor should be able to create one or more of these blocks, preferrably *on* the page that they're editing.
- And they should be able to place these peaces of content anywhere in their content.

An example would be an outstanding quote, that could be placed anywhere in the text, but not by creating/designing it at that place in the text, where it makes sense content-wise, but without having to design it, using the text editor itself.

Best case: They could even be able to chose whether they place it within the text in a big version or in a sidebar in a smaller version.

My problem:

- If it's a custom block type, how can I assign only a defined set of these to a certain content type? This only works with fields, does it?
- How can I add them to the editor form without cluttering it with forms for all possible types?

Comment: You can use the paragraphs module (http://dgo.to/paragraphs) to do this.

Comment: Paragraphs are not reusable - that’s one of the only downsides. Meaning, what you created on one node wont be available to “drop in” on others.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you're calling it a block-type of content it doesn't mean it will necessarily be the Block structure in Drupal.

Using Paragraphs you can create such structures for your nodes, where editors will be able to choose and reorder different types of paragraphs *you* have set up for them.

You can think of Paragraphs as Blocks to be inserted/reordered within content if you like. One Paragraph type in your case would have an image field and the quote/description field. The other paragraph type would have a video field and a description field.

You style each paragraph in your subtheme the way you want it too look like (for example you want the image to be centered above its description, but entire paragraph is floated within other fields, like Body text).

Paragraphs on the Edit form present as a Drop-down choice, so you won't see all available forms to start with and the interface isn't cluttered. You choose to add one paragraph at a time.

Once you have more than one paragraph added on the Edit page you can "collapse" them so they don't take a lot of space. This also makes them easy to reorder.

### For more advanced layout use Bricks

For more advanced layouts and flexible building of nodes you should use the Bricks module with the Layout Builder and Inline entity form.

Bricks is a more advanced/apstract module than Paragraphs. It lets you reuse Paragraphs and choose Layouts right on the Create/Edit page.

- [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs)
- [The Ultimate Tutorial for Drupal's Paragraphs Module](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/paragraphs-module/)
- [Using the Layout Builder Module for Drupal 8](https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/using-layout-builder-module-drupal-8)
- [Bricks​](https://www.drupal.org/project/bricks)
- [Bricks homepage](https://uibricks.com/)